# Can't compile drivers for rt8188eu wifi card

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, realtek

i have tried compiling [this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/tree/v4.1.8_9499) and also with the one i got from its manufactures. both are giving same make error..
When i make all....

```
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Downloads/rtl8188eu-4.1.8_9499/os_dep/ioctl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Downloads/rtl8188eu-4.1.8_9499] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

also my kernel headers(generic also) are up to date.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile a wrong branch for your kernel. Do this

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: And why is `https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu` the wrong branch? In https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new are only drivers for rtl8192ce, rtl8192se, rtl8192de, rtl8188ee, rtl8192ee, rtl8723ae, rtl8723be, and rtl8821ae. And I can compile the branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/tree/v4.1.8_9499 with the 3.x kernel.

Comment: This correct repo, but branch master should be tried. I can look what code change is, but it will work from rtlwifi_new either way.